# Making an object different colors along irregular lines

Tags: modeling

[image: Desired Lines]
[image: Exhibition of Ignorance]

Hi, I'm trying to make this heart five different colors along the lines, roughly, that you see here. I think I understand that I can't use these annotations to cut into the heart, but is it possible to make irregular cuts like this? I've been trying to cut it using boolean operations into 5 pieces that will fit together but I can't really figure out if that's even possible. Do I need to separate it into multiple pieces and color each separately, or is there a way to fill color along an irregular line? Or is the easiest way to do this actually using textures? I tried doing it this way because I don't know how to make a texture fit to the object and have no idea how to begin to find any tutorials to help this specific effort. Any help is much appreciated and I'm very new to this as you can probably tell so please be clear about how to find any tools you mention. Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried painting the heart with a brush ? - Do these pieces need to be separated for animation or simulation or can the heard stay intact ? - if you do not Need to break it, i would texture paint the heart ...

Comment: Do you need your heart to be separated in five different objects or is it one smooth object with just your illustration projected on it?

Comment: Hi Jade - you seem to have an image with the colors you want to appear on the heart?  Possibly image texturing may be the way to go - there are many tutorials on the web from simple to advanced, but the basic idea is use an Image Texture to drive the base color of your material, and do a UV Unwrap to create a UV Map which determines which parts of the image appear on what part of your mesh.

Comment: I’ve tried both breaking the heart and texturing it. I also tried looking for a brush and couldn’t find one. I really don’t care which of these work in the end, but I’ll try to figure out a brush as that seems easiest.

Comment: if you want the heart to look like its 2D version you need first to seam it correctly then unwrap

Comment: moonboots was correct, thank you for the help! well all of you were probably correct, but texturing it after a smart unwrap worked perfectly in the end